# Why is "$Ax=b$ is solvable $\iff AA^\mathsf{T}y=b$ is solvable" true?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

We have a random matrix A ($m\times n$), a vector $x$ from $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ and vectors $y$ and $b$ from $\mathbb{R^{m}}$.

Why is it true that $Ax=b$ has a unique solution $\iff$ $ A A^\mathsf{T} y=b$ has a unique solution?

Is it reasonable to approach this from a column space point of view? If $Ax=b$ has a unique solution then $b$ is in the column space of $A$, $b\in C(A)$. How can it be proved that the column spaces of $A$ and $AA^\top x$ are the same?

Comment: The usual thing is $A^T A x = A^T b.$ Your version seems wrong.

Comment: rank $A^TA$ = rank $A$

Comment: @WillJagy I can't see how the usual thing is true when matrices are non-square. Isn't it why we use this transformation (multiplying by the transpose on the left) that the original system is unsolvable and we want to find the "nearest" solution?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this is not true as stated. Take $m = 2$, $n=1$, $A = b = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Then
$$Ax = b$$
is the same as 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} x = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
which has the unique solution $x=1$.

On the other hand, $AA^T y = b$ is the same as
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} y = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
which has multiple solutions, e.g. $y = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ or $y = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you! I see it now. But what if we replaced "has a unique solution" with "has a unique or infinitely many solutions"? The rank of the resulting matrix will be definitely less than its order. Is there anything that could guarantee an infinite set of solutions?

Answer (score -1):

$\det(AA^T)=\det(A)\det(A^T)=(det(A))^2\ne0$

Comment: This assumes that $A$ is square.